# Cisco VPN and split tunneling

Tags: vpn, cisco, rdp, vnc, split-tunneling

I have a linux box with one NIC and Cisco VPN client installed. The problem is I want to use VNC while connected to the VPN, but the cisco router doesn't support split-tunneling and LAN access is disabled. I'm thinking of two solutions, but need some help about the setup. Does anybody have idea how to do it?

1. Override the routing after connected to the VPN network (tried with no luck)
2. Add virtual interface and again tweaking the routing (not sure if this is possible)

Answer (score 0):

Can you ask for the addition of split-tunneling support from whomever manages the Cisco router/firewall? If it's strict policy and/or political decision, you may not have any recourse.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the support.